# Grails withCriteria testing

Tags: grails, groovy

I'd like to test a "withCriteria" closure and am not sure how to go about it. I see how to mock out the withCriteria call, but not test the code within the closure. When running the test that executes the "withCriteria", I keep getting a MissingMethodException, even though the code runs fine under the normal flow of execution. Any ideas?
Thanks!
Steve

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wouldn't go that route. Instead I'd move the query into the domain class as a static finder method and test it directly in an integration test with real data. Then you can easily mock the helper method when it's called in a controller or service test.

```
class YourDomainClass {

...
   static List<YourDomainClass> findFooBar() {
      YourDomainClass.withCriteria {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Then in a unit test:

```
def results = [instance1, instance2, instance3]
YourDomainClass.metaClass.static.findFooBar = { -> results }
```

This way you test that the query works against the in-memory database in an integration test but it's easy to mock it in unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Burt's answer, check out named queries as described here:

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/05/24/more-grails-1-3-features/

You can then mock the property/method access in your unit tests as described by Burt.

Comment: The named queries are great, but I wasn't able to mock them in the unit tests.  Did you get that working or did you stick with integration tests?

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody mentioned the option to create a DSL to run other DSLs here's a full disclosure of this method. I use it quite often with very good results.

[Groovy/Grails testing DSLs](http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2011/01/groovygrails-dsl-testing.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's no mock implementation for Hibernate criteria at the present time. You'll need to use integration tests. However, Burt's recommendation of making this a static finder method is a good one for code organization. You should also look at named queries, described at http://www.grails.org/1.2+Release+Notes, for a nice syntax for this.